# What's causing scroll on top when I click radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[The page on my technical domain](https://t80469.hostua04.fornex.host/product/bag-bag/)
When I click on size or color attributes, on mobile version the page scrolls on top.
On computer version it's not visible, because we are already on the top of the screen.
The script of clicking on radios is

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '.variation-radios input', function() {
  jQuery('.variation-radios input:checked').each(function(index, element) {
    var $el = jQuery(element);
    var thisName = $el.attr('name');
    var thisVal  = $el.attr('value');
    jQuery('select[name="'+thisName+'"]').val(thisVal).trigger('change');
    jQuery('[name=quantity]').val(1);     
  });   
});
jQuery(document).on('woocommerce_update_variation_values', function() {
  jQuery('.variation-radios input').each(function(index, element) {
    var $el = jQuery(element);
    var thisName = $el.attr('name');
    var thisVal  = $el.attr('value');
    $el.removeAttr('disabled');
    if(jQuery('select[name="'+thisName+'"] option[value="'+thisVal+'"]').is(':disabled')) {
      $el.prop('disabled', true);
       jQuery('[name=quantity]').val(1);  
    }   
  });   
});
```

e.preventDefault() didn't help. I tried to paste it to the second string from the beginning of each script, and from the end, and inside. Almost everywhere.

I know about brilliant-perfect-great-thousands-of-millions-of-plugins, but I want to figure out in the code very much. I like to improve snippets for my own tasks. That snippet worked earlier. I've read that I have to place input inside label, I placed, but it didn't help too. What else can cause that jumping on top and what can fix it, if not input inside label and not preventDefault?

Comment: with only what you provide, I will give a "general" answer. If "scrolling top" on click, it'a often either the click generated a page reload, and/or the content to jump to is #. Check in dev tools if the click generate a page reload

Comment: I don't know. The url is the same but the html tag - one alone - is blinking, body is not blinking

Comment: I  try that, but I don't think it's right way jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery(this).offset().top + 0});